# PHP Function Error not Updating Password but receiving ok message

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to change the password from the user logged in. On the page it says the password was changed, but it does not change, not on the database and not at all. I have trying logging in with the new password, but just the old one remains to login.  I did refreshed the page and everything.  I am trying this for a couple of days and I wonder if someone would kindly spot my error. Tonight I thought it could be because the password is encrypted with md5 on the database. How would I proceed as I already tried a few things and do not work.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors","On");
<?php include "includes/connection.php" ?>
<?php
session_start();

if(@$_REQUEST["Submit"]=="Update")
{
$sql="update users set password ='$_REQUEST[newpassword]' where      user='$_SESSION[myusername]'";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) die('err: PROBLEM IN QUERY: '.mysql_error());
header("Location:changpass.php?msg=updated");
}
else
die('err: PROBLEM IN REQUEST');

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Change password</TITLE>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{

var formName=document.frm;

if(formName.newpassword.value == "")
{
document.getElementById("newpassword_label").innerHTML='Please Enter New Password';
formName.newpassword.focus();
return false;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("newpassword_label").innerHTML='';
}


if(formName.cpassword.value == "")
{
document.getElementById("cpassword_label").innerHTML='Enter ConfirmPassword';
formName.cpassword.focus();
return false;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("cpassword_label").innerHTML='';
}


if(formName.newpassword.value != formName.cpassword.value)
{
document.getElementById("cpassword_label").innerHTML='Passwords Missmatch';
formName.cpassword.focus()
return false;
}
else
{
document.getElementById("cpassword_label").innerHTML='';
}
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {font-weight: bold}
.style7 {
color: yellow;
font-size: 24px;
}
.style9 {
color: #FF6666;
font-weight: bold;
}
.style12 {
color: #666666;
font-weight: bold;
}
.style14 {color: #CC0033; font-weight: bold; }
-->
</style>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<form action="changpass.php" method="post" name="frm" id="frm" onSubmit="return   validate();">
<table width="47%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#666666">
<td colspan="2"><span class="style7">Change Password</span></td>
</tr>
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && $_REQUEST['msg'] == 'updated') { ?>
<tr bgcolor="#666666">
<td colspan="2"><span class="style7">Password has been changed successfully.</span></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span class="style14">New Password:</span></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="password" name="newpassword" id="newpassword"    size="20" autocomplete="off"/>&nbsp; <label id="newpassword_label" 

class="level_msg"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><span class="style14">Confirm Password:</span></td>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" size="20"  autocomplete="off">&nbsp; <label id="cpassword_label" 

class="level_msg"></td>
</tr><tr bgcolor="#666666"><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"   name="Submit" value="Update" /></td>
</tr></table><a href="index.php">Home</a></form></BODY></HTML>`
```

Comment: I think you should be using $_GET (not $_REQUEST)

Comment: Check `mysql_error()`. (Also, you got a possible mysql injection in this code)

Comment: @Blauesocke good point, he should probably look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555255/how-can-i-protect-this-code-from-sql-injection-a-bit-confused?rq=1

Comment: No matter you will solve this issue or not, consider using `PDO` or `mysqli` for future (PREPARED STATEMENTS). Your mysql code is not secure. If you still want to stick to mysql, you are not even using `mysql_real_escape_string` for protecetion. Try to write SQL statements like this: `mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE name='".myqsl_real_escape_string($name)."'")`...

Comment: Good advice, about security, I am quite interested, but I will stick to this code as I already spent a lot of time on it. And, in future I will try to learn PDO. :-)

Comment: Thank you for advice, I will stick to this now and be more professional next time as I am already working on this for some time.

Comment: Please check my answer update. Let's do some error findings at first.

Answer (score 2):

I enhanced your code:

```
<?php
    if ($_REQUEST['Submit'] == "Update")
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `password`='".$_REQUEST['newpassword']."' WHERE `user`='".$_SESSION['myusername']."'";
        mysql_query($sql);
        header("Location: changpass.php?msg=updated");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

**To use this code make sure following:**

1) You are having correct Submit button, example is following:

> `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update" />`

2) You are having correct password field, example is following:

> `<input type="password" name="newpassword" value="" />`

3) Session has to be set under key `myusername`

4) Make sure your table fields and names are okay. Do more debugging.

If this still won't solve, add form code for further investigation.

**EDIT**

Here is interpretation of this code with for some basic debugging purposes that might help:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['Submit']) && $_REQUEST['Submit'] == "Update")
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) trigger_error("DEBUG: SESSION VARIABLE IS NOT SET");
        if (!isset($_REQUEST['newpassword']) || empty($_REQUEST['newpassword'])) trigger_error("DEBUG: NEW PASSWORD IS NOT GIVEN");

        $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `password`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['newpassword'])."' WHERE `user`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['myusername'])."'";
        $qw = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$qw) trigger_error("DEBUG: MYSQL RESPONDED WITH ERROR - ".mysql_error());

        header("Location: changpass.php?msg=updated");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

**UPDATE: Debugging step #1**

Change a code in your php file to this and tell us if any error messages show up.

```
if(@$_REQUEST["Submit"]=="Update")
{
    $sql="update users set password ='$_REQUEST[newpassword]' where     user='$_SESSION[myusername]'";
    if (!mysql_query($sql)) die('err: PROBLEM IN QUERY: '.mysql_error());
    header("Location:changpass.php?msg=updated");
}
else
    die('err: PROBLEM IN REQUEST');
```